# Can I choose desktop (vs server) build, for server hardware?

Tags: server, system-installation, gui

Do the physical servers support high graphical interfaces ? 
I ask this question in order to see if installing a Linux desktop instead of a linux server on a physical server won't lead me to low graphical performances.

Comment: "the physical servers" is meaningless.  What graphics support your particular server hardware has obviously depends on what server hardware you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it's a server then I would install the server version and then install a desktop like `ubuntu-desktop`. Because you get the server kernels that you want and you get a GUI which is nice and easy.

Install the desktop by typing in the command line, `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, or whatever GUI you want.

Comment: But why do I need to install a server version before a desktop one ? For which technical reasons ?

Comment: As Alvar pointed out, you will get the server kernel and options for installing server services (LAMP, mail server, SSH server, etc.) during the server-edition install. This is somewhat easier than installing those packages and services on a standard desktop-edition install.

Comment: +1 That's exactly what I tried to point out. it's easier to install the server first and then the desktop you want.

Comment: But my question is about the graphical performances: will I have good or low graphical performances if I install ubuntu desktop on a physical server ?

Comment: @begueradj you wont have any less performance than if you installed the desktop.